Создание матрицы списков
Всем привет!
Застрял на задачке по циклам.
Не могу понять как заполнять строки матрицы числами, согласно представленного на скрине правила
Суть задачи:
На вход программе подаются два натуральных числа  и . Напишите программу, которая создает матрицу размером ×, заполнив её в соответствии с образцом.
Вот что у меня пока получилось:
def create_matrix(n, m):
  matrix = []
  for i in range(n):
    row = [m] * m
    matrix.append(row)
  return matrix

Образец ниже.
Прошу извинить за корявый формат кода, на телефоне не работют кнопки оформления


А что именно не умеете делать?

Пока получается вот такой код, не могу понять как через range заполнить матрицу цифрами по тому правилу, которое указано на скрине т.е. я не прошу решить ее полностью за меня, прошу подсказать по конкретной проблеме, с которой уже долго бьюсь

Код добавьте в сам вопрос, и опишите что не так

Для начала сделайте нормальный цикл в цикле. Просто умножением списка ничего не получится.

Для начала сделаем традиционное добавление элементов в список.  Такой код проще отлаживать.
Каждый элемент зависит и от номера строки и от номера столбца. Использование остатка от деления %m позволяет ограничить диапазон чисел и обеспечить цикличность.
def create_matrix(n, m):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(m):
            row.append((j+i)%m+1)
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix

Теперь используем вложенные списковые включения (list comprehension), которые делают то же самое:
def create_matrixx(n, m):
    return [[(j+i)%m+1 for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]


Если нужен форматированный вывод как в примере, то в первую функцию, которую для Вас написал MBo, добавьте следующий код:
for idx, el in enumerate(matrix):
    el = map(str, el)
    matrix[idx] = " ".join(el)

return "\n".join(matrix)

